# How can I populate a textbox with database values from a combobox?

Tags: c#

I am quite new to C# and I am trying to populate fill several textboxes with data from a selected combobox.
I have my main window with the textboxes and comboboxes and a separate class for the connection to the database (I am using XAMPP/PhpMyAdmin).
I managed to fill the comboboxes with the data from the database, but I cannot fill the texboxes from the selected combobox.
I checked other questions and tutorials, but all I managed to achieve is to get the primary key into the text box, but I need different columns from the table, depending on the textbox.

I populated the combobox from the database:

```
void Completez_Combo_Furnizor()
{
    combo_furnizor = DB_Furnizori.Combo_Furnizor();
    comboBoxFurnizor.Items.Clear();
    comboBoxFurnizor.DataSource = combo_furnizor;
    comboBoxFurnizor.ValueMember = "id_furnizor";
    comboBoxFurnizor.DisplayMember = "nume";
}
```

I double clicked on the combobox and wrote the following, but all I can get is the primary key (the first column). In the textbox, I need to get the 7th column (which is a double type.

```
private void comboBoxFurnizor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxPret.Text = comboBoxFurnizor.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

And this is from the database class (DB_Furnizori.cs), where I open the connection and have multiple queries for the database.

```
public static DataTable Combo_Furnizor()
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand comboFurnizor = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from furnizori ORDER BY nume", conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter adaptc = new MySqlDataAdapter(comboFurnizor);
    DataTable combo_furnizori = new DataTable();
    adaptc.Fill(combo_furnizori);
    conn.Close();
    return combo_furnizori;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For your SelectedIndexChanged Method :

```
private void comboBoxFurnizor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    textBoxPret.Text = comboBoxFurnizor.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

You need to make another call to the database and retrieve the data you want using the values/Id (or whatever is the unique identifier) from the combobox. If you're trying to retrieve data on a selected index change you need to reference some type of data source for me I used a DataSet instead of DataTable (makes retrieving values in cells easier):

```
string StoredProc = "GetItemNotes";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProc, conn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(ds);
```

For populating the data within my Textbox I did this:

```
 Notes.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();
```